# Jenkins запуск build проекта после push

Tags: gitlab, build, jenkins

Доброго времени суток. Первый раз столкнулся с задачами CI. Проблема - не получается адекватно настроить Jenkins. Что требуется: после push проекта на GitLab (именно после push, это важно), Jenkins должен попытаться собрать проект.

Шаги предпринятые для решения этой проблемы:

1. Jenkins сервер поднят и настроен, и работает по адресу jenkinsaddres:port
2. На Jenkins сервере есть GitLab connection опция которая настроена на gitlabhost, GitLab API token задан и test connection возвращает радостное success.
3. Добавлен проект, Source Code Management, Repository URL, Credentials, Branch Specifier настроены.
4. В проекте опции Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab CI Service URL: jenkinsaddres:port/project/test активна, GitLab Triggers: Push events опция так же активна.
5. GitLabProject -> Settings -> Web hook -> jenkinsaddres:port/project/test, и опция Push Events тоже активна.

Проект build'ится по расписанию, или вручную но никак не хочет собираться даже при тестовой отправке hook'а с GitLab. POST сообщение доходит следующего вида `source: gitlabhost; destination: jenkinsaddres; Protocol: HTTP; info: POST /project/test HTTP/1.1 (application/json)`. Ответ: адреса верные поэтому не буду их показывать, поле `info: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found (text/html)`.

Если на Jenkins выключить все secure опции, и посылать hook на `jenkinsaddres:port/job/test`(сюда он стягивает проекты) то тогда объект все-таки находится: Found. Но оказывается что изменений Jenkins не видит (Not Modified), думаю поэтому проект и не ребилдится.

Comment: Вы настраивали у тригеров poll SCM? Это позволяет через определенный промежуток времени проверять появился ли коммит, и если да, то собирать проект.  И я правильно понимаю, что Вам нужно собирать проект, когда появился новый коммит?

Comment: 1. Так точно, через триггеры все работает прекрасно. Но такой вариант решения не подходит. (по сути сейчас он и реализован).
2. Да, когда один из разработчиков вносит какие-либо изменения в проект, после отправки изменений на репозиторий (git push), Jenkins пересобирает проект.

Comment: poll - не лучший способ. Хуки гораздо эффективнее, реакция в них быстрее, а нагрузка на хостинг репозиториев - меньше.

Answer (score 4):

Борюсь с подобной же проблемой. Статья https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/298 дала следующую подсказку - тестируют с POST а не GET, что возвращает 403 так как "anonymous is missing the Job/Build permission". Два решения по починке
https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/375
Если не заработает после правки - стоит проверить имя проекта. Если что есть URL encoded - это проблемма
Так Unit Tests не работает, а UnitTests работает.

Comment: Если я использую /job/test то он все находит. Обменивается радостными Found, но сборку проекта не запускает все равно (на данный момент все политики безопасности отключены).

Comment: Попробуйте через триггер с токеном, там не должна требоваться авторизация.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать триггер с токеном, он позволяет запускать сборку даже анонимному пользователю. Например, в моем дженкинсе аноним имеет разрешение только на просмотр (Read) задач и сборок. Но хуки работают из Гитлаба, curl'ом и просто через браузер.

В конфигурации задачи `example_jenkins_job`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хук в Гитлабе:

```
http://jenkinsaddress:port/job/example_jenkins_job/build?token=secret_token
```

Или, если задача параметризованная:

```
http://jenkinsaddress:port/job/example_jenkins_job
  /buildWithParameters?token=secret_token
```

В этом случае будет запущена сборка с дефолтными значениями параметров. Вы можете передавать собственные значения параметров следующим образом:

```
http://jenkinsaddress:port/job/example_jenkins_job
  /buildWithParameters?token=secret_token&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Можно добавить причину сборки: `&cause=Cause+Text` Она сохранится в информации о сборке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в логе сборки, первой строкой:

```
Started by remote host 127.0.0.1 with note: Cause Text
```

Comment: А можно как-нибудь запрашивать и передавать через hook deploy key? Чтобы не заводить jenkins пользователя.

Comment: @Dark_Fox так и не нужно заводить пользователя. Подразумевается, что токен у вас секретный и его достаточно для авторизации на запуск сборки именно этой задачи. Если не раскрывать кому попало конфигурацию задачи в Дженкинсе и настройки хуков в Гитлабе, то токен действительно будет секретным.

Comment: @Dark_Fox это у меня пример `secret_token`, а вы можете использовать что-нибудь вроде `421a31fdd7e369416e4f8469beb3826fa07bb9a6`. Пропорционально важности сборки и собственной подозрительности. ))

Comment: спасибо и последний вопрос тут задам чтобы новую ветку не создавать. Как правильно воспользоваться deploy key? Ключ создаю /jenkins_home/.ssh/rsa права на ключ выставлены на пользователя jenkins, в gitlab,e данный ключ добавлен как deploy key, и в конфиге проекта в таком случае так же используется ssh:project_gitlab_ref. Permission denied. На всякий случай пробовал вариант с созданием файла config содержащего Host repname.gitlabaddr, HostName gitlabaddr, User git, IdentityFile /path/id_rsa.pub. Не помогло.

Comment: @Dark_Fox лучше всё-таки задать новый вопрос, так он вместе с ответом будет полезен будущим читателям. А комментарии поисковиками не индексируются. Так что жду ссылку на вопрос )

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568558/jenkins-gitlab-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-deploy-key