# Jenkins + Gitlab, как правильно воспользоваться deploy key?

Tags: gitlab, key, jenkins

День добрый. Как правильно воспользоваться deploy key? Ключ создаю `/jenkins_home/.ssh/rsa`, права на ключ выставлены на пользователя jenkins, в gitlab'e данный ключ добавлен как deploy key, и в конфиге проекта в таком случае так же используется `ssh:project_gitlab_ref`. Permission denied. На всякий случай пробовал вариант с созданием файла `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config` содержащего:

```
Host repname.gitlabaddr
HostName gitlabaddr
User jenkins
IdentityFile /path/id_rsa_name
```

Не помогло. Видимо как-то не так указываю HostName. Потому что:

```
stderr: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: home
/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Сейчас указано в виде `gitlab.2d.local-testv3`

Comment: */var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: home* — а что на самом деле записано в этом файле? приложите его содержимое прямо к вопросу, т.к. в комментариях невозможно отобразить форматированный текст.

Comment: Так я его содержимое к вопросу и приложил. Простите, не написал полный путь к нему в вопросе, только название. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: но там нет слова *home*, присутствующего в сообщении об ошибке. откуда берётся это слово?

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы. Поправил. Но принимать deploy все еще откзывается по причине Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: простите, не понял, что именно вы поправили. вы приводите содержимое файла из четырёх строчек, ни в одной из которых нет слова `home`, которое упоминается в сообщении об ошибке. кстати, в четвёртой из строк файла наверняка неправильный путь указан: файл `/path/id_rsa.pub.`. во-первых, вряд ли имя файла заканчивается на точку, во-вторых, судя по имени, это файл с публичным ключом, а не с секретным, который должен быть указан в директиве `identityfile`.

Comment: Насчет точки, в конце файла ее нет, это я в процессе оформления по инерции поставил. Ключик тоже поправил на приватный, Теперь identityfile /path/id_rsa_rep. Пока по прежнему permission denied. Я думаю что я неверно указываю Host. gitlab.company.local:my_group/rep.git так выглядит ssh ссылка к репозиторию. В интернете натыкался на 2 варианта записи как-то: rep.gitlab.company.local и gitlab.company.local-rep но группы в таких примерах отсутствуют.

Answer (score 2):

В настройках Jenkins зайдите в <kbd>Manage Jenkins</kbd> > <kbd>Manage Credentials</kbd> и там заведите новое `SSH username with private key.`

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках конкретной задачи, там же где указывается путь к репозиторию, выберите используемые credentials.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Jenkins сразу попытается залогиниться в указанный репозиторий. Если не сможет покажет сообщение об ошибке.

Авторизация нужна только когда у вашего проекта уровень видимости Private или Protected. Если не хотите настраивать авторизацию, выбирайте уровень Public:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проект Private. Как раз и пытаюсь получить к нему доступ с помощью deploy key. Но пока все-равно требует авторизации =( Т.е. вариант с ключом пока не срабатывает.

Comment: @Dark_Fox в гитлабе ключ с тем же именем добавлен?

Comment: С тем же именем пользователя jenkins или с тем же именем файла-ключа? Попробовал и так и так, ну то есть и jenkins и id_rsa.keyname.pub. Так же Permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Решение которое подошло мне. После создания публичного ключа и установки его на gitlab, для jenkins пользователя создаем конфигурационный файл /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config со следующим содержимым:

```
Host gitlab.loc
User jenkins
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/privatekey
```

Все, этого оказалось достаточно.